# Failed to mound sd card ERROR

Tags: samsung, sd-card

I tried updating software on my galaxy ace and it was downloading then it got stuck. so I switched it off then back on and it says failed to mount sd card. I can't get into recovery mode. please help!!

Comment: Did you update the devices firmware? Or did you update some apps via the play store? Either way... reflashing the stock firmware might resolve your issue. Visit [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-S5830i/) and download a firmware - follow the install instructions on the bottom of the download page.